# SQL Order By in and varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I want to order a column of type nvarchar that contains integers and strings. I want to order first the integers ASC then the strings.
This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Password] 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Password
```

The result is `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, K1, K2, N`.

I want `1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, K1, K2, N`.

Comment: What will be your expected result for `1 2 1K K1` ?

Comment: Storing the password in a plain-text field is a horrible idea, if this is your case, please check [Best way to store password in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Password] 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Password) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Password) = 1 THEN CAST(Password AS INT) ELSE 0 END,
    Password
```

plz try this.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't answer the question you think it does. For instance, `ISNUMERIC('£')` will return 1, but you'll get an error trying to convert that to `int`.

Comment: As I say, try running your sample code where `Password` just contains the `£` sign. You'll get an error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : ohk. getting you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : But in Ibraheem case , there aren't any special characters so it works fine.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani - it was just a single example. There are plenty of others - e.g. `'1d1'` will also fall over here. As will `'.'`. The point is, the function answers a question nobody wants to ask and so any use of it is almost always a sign of breakage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Thanks, I am getting so much from you. Now onward I will take care of all this things.

Answer (score 2):

*ISNUMERIC doesn't answer the question you think it does. For instance, **`ISNUMERIC('£') will return 1`**, but you'll get an error trying to convert that to int. – Damien_The_Unbeliever*

Create this function in your database which is **better** than the in-built ISNUMERIC(), and **always** exact!

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsAllDigits (@MyString VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
         SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @MyString NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS IsAllDigits
        )
```

Then use this code for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Password] 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN IsAllDigits([Password]) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN IsAllDigits([Password]) = 1 THEN CAST([Password] AS INT) ELSE 0 END,
    [Password]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Patindex` for this

```
Declare @Tasks table(id [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL)

insert into @tasks values ('1'),('7'),('2'), ('12'),('23'),('10'),('K1'), ('K2'), ('P'), ('N')

SELECT * FROM @tasks
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(id)=1 
  THEN CAST(id as int)

  WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',id) > 1 
  THEN CAST(
    LEFT(
      id,
      PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',id) - 1
    ) as int)

  ELSE 2147483648
END, 


CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(id)=1 
  THEN NULL

  WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',id) > 1 
  THEN SUBSTRING(
      id,
      PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',id) ,
      50
    ) 

  ELSE id
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Password] 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Password ASC
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```

$query_test = "SELECT DISTINCT `OCPR`.password 
                FROM `OCPR` 
                WHERE `OCPR`.password IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY `OCPR`.password";

Answer (score 1):

you could do it using the ISNUMERIC function.
Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Password] 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Password])=1 THEN CONVERT(int,[Password]) ELSE 99999999 END,
[Password]
```

Hope this helped ;)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't answer the question you think it does. For instance, `ISNUMERIC('£')` will return 1, but you'll get an error trying to convert that to `int`.